# what is use of DataImportScheduler in Solr? can it handle delta imports without schema changes?

Tags: search, solr

I have configured DataImportScheduler in Solr which hits a URL specified in the params attribute in properties file, can it handle the delta imports without making a change to the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

DataImportScheduler's sole purpose is to simply fire HTTP Post command with params and interval specified in its properties file to allow easy scheduling on Windows servers (where there are no cron jobs). It has nothing to do with db schema.

You're not allowed to add nullable [timestamp column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) in your tables?

Comment: actually the problem is i want configure delta imports but i dont want to change my database schema and add lastModified column.

Answer (score 0):

DIH cannot handle delta imports without the last modified column in your tables.
DIH delta works by comparing the last successful timestamp of your build with the last modified column and pick up only those modified later than the last successful build.

e.g.

```
<entity name="item" pk="ID"   query="SELECT * FROM item"   deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM item
    WHERE id = '${dataimporter.delta.id}'"   deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM item
    WHERE last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
```

However, if there is no indicator in the table to indicate the same the delta import would not be able to indentify the new added/updated rows.
Also, the rows deleted should be probably soft deletes to enable identification.
If you do hard deletes the documents would still be in your index, even though removed from the tables.